# How does Provider and connect work in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

#### 1- `Provider`

Why do we need to wrap all our components inside `Provider` ?

#### 2- `connect`:

How is `connect` passing redux store as `props` to components ?

#### 3- Can we build our own `Provider` and `connect` ?

Below is a fully working simple React Redux example that just displays a name from the redux store and uses React Redux `connect` and `Provider`, so how `ConnectedComponent` can simply access `this.props.name` ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";

var defaultState = {
  name: "Amr"
};

function rootReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  return state;
}

var store = createStore(rootReducer);


class ConnectedComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    name: state.name
  };
}
ConnectedComp = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedComp);



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedComp />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

A fully working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/lpvnxro7n7

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To be able to understand how `Provider` and `connect` work we need to understand 2 concepts in React

### 1- Context api:

Context is a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass the props down manually at every level, you can learn more about [context here](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html#updating-context)

### 2- Higher Order Component (HOC):

A higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component but before returning the new component you can pass extra custom props and then return it, you can learn more about [HOC here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

---

### 3- Build our own `Provider` and `connect`

Now that we understand both Context and Higher Order Component, we will use them to create the same fully working example in the question but using our own built `myProvider` and `myConnect`

---

#### `MyProvider`

```
//This is how we utilize React Context and create MyProvider component that will pass store to all its child components automatically
//This is also known by Provider pattern
class MyProvider extends Component {
  //By adding the getChildContext function and childContextTypes, React passes the information down automatically to any component in the subtree
  getChildContext() {
    const { store } = this.props
    return { store }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

MyProvider.childContextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

---

#### `myConnect`

```
//This is the Higher Order Component
function myConnect(mapStateToPropsFunc) {
  return function (WrappedComp) {
    var myHOC = class HOC extends Component {
      render() {
        //Now we access redux store using react context api as it will be passed by MyProvider automatically to all child components
        var myStore = this.context.store.getState();
        //mapStateToPropsFunc is just used to structure the props required by the component so we pass to mapStateToPropsFunc the whole store and then it returns a mapped object with required props thats why it is well known by mapStateToProps
        var storeToBePassed = mapStateToPropsFunc(myStore);
        return (
          //We pass the result from executing mapStateToPropsFunc to the wrapped component and this is how the components get passed props from redux store
          <WrappedComp {...storeToBePassed} />
        )
      }
    }

    //We need to define contextTypes otherwise context will be empty
    myHOC.contextTypes = {
      store: PropTypes.object
    };

    //return new component that has access to redux store as props mapped using mapStateToProps function
    return myHOC;
  }
}
```

---

#### The same simple example using our own `MyProvider` and `myConnect`

```
//Note that we removed react-redux library
import React, { Component, Children } from "react";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";

var defaultState = {
  name: "Amr"
};

function rootReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  return state;
}

var store = createStore(rootReducer);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    //Here we use our own built myProvider and pass store
    return (
      <MyProvider store={store}>
        <ConnectedComp />
      </MyProvider>
    );
  }
}

class ConnectedComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
    );
  }
}

//mapStateToProps is a normal function that get store as parameter and return the required props by that component, btw this function can have any name
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    name: state.name
  };
}

//Here we use our own built myConnect
ConnectedComp = myConnect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedComp);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

You can test the above implementation here https://codesandbox.io/s/727pl0mqoq

---

This example is a simple illustration of how react-redux `Provider` and `connect` can be built by utilizing both React `Context` and `HOC`.

This give us a better understanding of why we use `Provider`, `connect` and `mapStateToProps`

Comment: Great stuff. I have one question. Could you explain how updates in `store` (through `MyProvider`) cause updates/re-renders to occur in the 'connected' components? What if `store` is a custom object (i.e. not using redux)?

Comment: The only purpose of `MyProvider` is to pass the redux store or any custom object to all children automatically, but keep in mind that the passed store can be accessed ONLY by context api as you can see in the answer this part `this.context.store.getState();` , this is where `MyConnect`  becomes handy as it will read the data from context and pass it as `props` to the connected component, finally the component will update/render because of the fact that react will trigger render once a component `props` or `state` is updated, in our case the cause is the props update passed from `MyConnect` HOC

Comment: for `MyProvider` function, why `getChildContext` not simply returns `this.props.store`..

Comment: You need to return an object from `getChildContext` and it will need to match our defined `childContextTypes` structure, if you return `this.props.store` whatever the value returned from this line `var store = createStore(rootReducer);` will be returned, it will be something like this `{ getState: function, dispatch: function, ...etc }` which is not correct, what you need to return is this `{ store: { getState: function, dispatch: function, ... }}` because later you will use context in `myConnect` in the following way `this.context.store.getState()`

Comment: personally i think this would have been better, `connect(stateProps, dispatchProps, state)(Component)` instead of having a provider.